# Reference vs. value copy for PHP arrays?

Tags: php

I am missing something obvious.  Here's a trivial piece of PHP, littered with debug echos:

```
function echo_rows(&$res) {
    $rows= array();
    while ($row= $res->fetch()) {
           echo $row['ccorID'] . "\r\n";
        $rows[]= $row;
           echo $rows[0]['ccorID'] . "\r\n";
    }

    echo "---.---\r\n";
    echo count($rows) . "\r\n";
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        echo $row['ccorID'] . "\r\n";
    }
    echo json_encode($rows);
}
```

Here's what I see in the response:

```
0
0
3
3
13
13
182
182
---.---
4
182
182
182
182
```

It seems perfectly clear to me that :-

- I have 4 rows of data
- `$rows[]= $row;`  does NOT perform a value copy, despite what it says here http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Anyone got any idea what I need to do to get a copy of $row (which is an associative array)?

Thanks.

EDIT:  Since many of you are so insistent to know what $res is, here is the class.  I genuinely believe that this is more likely to confuse than enlighten (hence the omission from my OP).

```
class mysqlie_results {
    private $stmt;
    private $paramArray= array(); 
    private $assocArray= array(); 

    public function __construct(&$stmt) {
        $this->stmt= $stmt;
        $meta= $stmt->result_metadata(); 

        while ($colData= $meta->fetch_field()) {
            $this->paramArray[]= &$this->assocArray[$colData->name]; 
        }

        call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_result'),$this->paramArray); 
        $meta->close(); 
    } 

    public function __destruct() {
        $this->stmt->free_result();
    } 

    public function fetch() { 
        return $this->stmt->fetch()? $this->assocArray : false;
    } 
}
```

Comment: You're right.  It does not perform a value copy.  It performs a variable copy.  So if the variable is a reference, the resulting array element will be a reference as well...  If it's not a reference, it will perform the value copy (just like any other variable copy)...  And the value copy bit you cite is when you copy the entire element, not inserting records...

Comment: Please rename your title!

Comment: For some reason the first element of `$rows` is being overwritten here.

Comment: What is the desired output of this code?  

Also, should you be using fetch_assoc()?

Comment: What does `var_dump($rows)` say? It's possible that you're in fact assigning references not actual values.

Comment: Exactly what does `$res->fetch()` return, i.e. what is `$row`?

Comment: Interesting, I get dumb when using php.

Comment: What bothers me is this line: `echo $rows[0]['ccorID'] . "\r\n";`.  That should always print the same exact value (the first that was assigned)...  And that proves this is a reference issues.  (Since the first element changes on each iteration).  Try adding `unset($row)` before the end of the first `while` block...

Comment: @ircmaxell: It certainly seems like it couldn't be this code, or the second, fourth, sixth, and eighth lines in the output would be the same, and they clearly aren't.

Comment: Wow!  Thanks guys.  I am normally lucky to get 1 answer on SO but to have this kind of response.  I am overwhelmed.  So, @ar: why should I change the title?  It seems that self-deprecation attracts more readers than technical subjects (though, I grant you, the latter would be preferable).

Comment: @all:  $res->fetch returns an array, not a reference.  It is however quite clear from the output that ALL array assignments in my code are handled by reference.  And this would not surprise me in the least were this eg JS (where this is documented behaviour).  What got me here is that PHP manual is categorical: "Array assignment always involves value copying. Use the reference operator to copy an array by reference."  This is quite evidently not so.  Which leaves me to wonder how one does force a copy...

Comment: @Eli:  Yes, I would like to use fetch_assoc.  In fact, my fetch is doing a fetch_assoc.  It is just that my PHP documentation does not mention a fetch_assoc...

Comment: What type of resource is `$res`?  That is, what API are you calling?

Comment: Gosh.  Everyone's so curious about my ->fetch.  My ->fetch is but the standard mysqli_stmt::fetch modified such that it returns an associative array (by value !!  no "&" in sight!) of all the columns returned from the database.  That is, $res is my own class creation (mysqli_stmt contained, not derived).

Comment: Ah but does it return by value or do you return an internal array specific for your wrapper (does your wrapper do `return $this->var`?)

I still have to agreed with you though, this is weird behavior even so.

Comment: @Eli:  I found the fetch_assoc in mysqli_result, which I did not see before.  This is EXACTLY what I should be using, and it might even fix this problem.  I give it a shot.  Thanks for rubbing my nose in :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at

```
    while ($colData= $meta->fetch_field()) {
        $this->paramArray[]= &$this->assocArray[$colData->name]; 
    }

    call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_result'),$this->paramArray);
```

There you have your reference(s) and that's causing the trouble. If you copy an array that contains a reference the result is still an array containing a reference.

Try

```
while ($row= $res->fetch()) {
  var_dump($row);
```

and you will see that $row also contains references. All those corresponding elements in `paramArray`, `assocArray` and `$row` actually reference the same value. And thus when you invoke `return $this->stmt->fetch()` it doesn't only affect `paramArray` but *all* those references, all the way down to $rows since `$rows[]= $row;` still only copies the array but does not "de-reference" the elements.

Comment: That's not my reading of the situation.  The fancy bit in this code is paramArray, which is indeed an array of references.  But it is merely used to trick mysqli::fetch (via bind_result) into depositing its values into assocArray, the vanilla structure.  When fetch returns assocArray, it is returning an array of values, I think.

Comment: @Ollie2893: "When fetch returns assocArray, it is returning an array of values, I think." - no, it does not. Stop assuming/speculating, test! Especially when it's as easy as putting _one line of code_ in there as suggested.

Comment: You are quite right - I should have tried.  var_dump reveals indeed that all elements are references, as you write.  The logic why this happens defeats me - it does not match my expectations (based on C etc.).

Turns out, though, that Eli was right all along.  When I morphed my code from mysql to mysqli, I was somehow steered down the road of ::prepare and ::execute, which landed me in the pickle of having to write my own fetch_assoc (which went so wrong).  Using ::query instead, I end up with mysqli_result::fetch_all, and that's SOOOO much easier.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

edit: Using object was only a guess. It turns out that the problem is caused by references as others have guessed before.

Since we don't know (yet) what $res is and what `$res->fetch()` actually returns let me try to replicate the behaviour.

```
<?php
$res = new Foo;
echo_rows($res);

function echo_rows(&$res) {
  // as provided in the question
}

class Foo extends ArrayObject {  
  protected $bar, $counter;

  public function fetch() {
    if ( ++$this->counter > 4 ) {
      return false;
    }
    else {
      $this->bar['ccorID'] = $this->counter;
      return $this->bar;
    }
  }

  public function __construct() {
    $this->bar = new ArrayObject;
    $this->counter = 0;
  }
}
```

prints

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
---.---
4
4
4
4
4
[{"ccorID":4},{"ccorID":4},{"ccorID":4},{"ccorID":4}]
```

The reason is, that all elements in $rows point to the same underlying object (see http://docs.php.net/language.oop5.references) since my class Foo always returns the same object and just modifies the state of this single object.

---

update: "what might the manual mean when it says "Use the reference operator to copy an array by reference"?"

Let's start with this script

```
<?php
$arr = array();
$s = '';

$b = array();
$b['foo'] = $arr;
$b['bar'] = $s;

$b['foo']['bar'] = 1;
$b['bar'] = 'xyz';

var_dump($arr, $s);
```

the output is

```
array(0) {
}
string(0) ""
```

i.e. `$b['foo']['bar'] = 1;` and `$b['bar'] = 'xyz';` didn't change $arr and $s since the array contains copies of the values.

Now change the two assignments to use references

```
$b['foo'] = &$arr;
$b['bar'] = &$s;
```

and the output changes to

```
array(1) {
  ["bar"]=>
  int(1)
}
string(3) "xyz"
```

i.e. the elements are not copies.

Comment: +1 since objects are passed by reference by default (well, the instance is anyway)...

Comment: Not exactly references, but close, see http://docs.php.net/language.oop5.references

Comment: I completely agree with you guys.  That's clearly what's happening.  I am merely put out because the PHP manual states: "Array assignment always involves value copying. Use the reference operator to copy an array by reference."  It is clearly not so.

Comment: @Ollie2893: The "value" of a variable that points to an object is the object-id that is used to point to the object (php5). A copy of that object-id still points to the same object. What you've expected is a _clone_ of the object but that doesn't happen implicitly (again php5), see http://docs.php.net/language.oop5.references and http://docs.php.net/clone

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with this concept, Volker.  I don't quite agree with you, though, that one can read the PHP manual entry in this manner.  Following your logic, what might the manual mean when it says "Use the reference operator to copy an array by reference"?

Comment: I just followed your link http://docs.php.net/clone and inserted clone like so: $rows[]= clone $row;  No joy.  PHP puked because array() does not support a clone method.  If you were right, the lack of a clone method would not make sense to me.  It does make sense, though, if we believed the manual that "Array assignment always involves value copying" - explicit cloning would be tautologous.

Comment: a) see update  b) `clone` only works on objects. `Since we don't know (yet) what $res is and what $res->fetch() actually returns let me try to replicate the behaviour.` - that still applies. Using objects was only a guess and it replicates the behaviour you've described. For a more accurate guesses I need more accurate information ;-) Exactly what is $res? Exactly what does $res->fetch() return? Can you show us the code and/or documentation?

Comment: Sorry, just spotted your update above.  The behaviour that you observe is exactly the behaviour documented, the behaviour I want.  Your $b['foo']= $arr; is the equivalent to my $rows[]= $row;  Yet you arrive at a perfect copy of $arr (your assignment $b['foo']['bar']= 1; does not change $arr) yet my $rows[] does not receive a perfect copy of my $row.  (I do NOT use &$row.  Not anywhere.)

Comment: May be I could ask you to try this:

$arr = array(1,2);

    $b = array();
    $b[] = $arr;
    $arr[0]= 5;
    var_dump($b);

You should of course get (1,2);  I unfortunately get (5,2)...

Comment: I get (1,2) (php 5.3.3/php.net build/cli/winxp). Which version of php do you use?

Comment: See EDIT to OP.  I copied the complete class description for $res.

Comment: I'm on 5.3.0.  By the way, I should qualify that I did not try my own suggestion.  When I said that I get (5,2), then that is is what results in the original code.  As I commented in reply to Bill Karwin, the response from echo_rows isn't predictable.  There's a certain invocation - the one for which the function was originally written - where the results are (1,2).  For others it's (5,2).  Bill may be right.  It could be optimization.

Comment: Ollie2893: "I should qualify that I did not try my own suggestion." - arghhhh!

Answer (score 1):

PHP core developer Johannes Schlüter says [Do not use PHP references.](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/125-Do-not-use-PHP-references.html)  References in PHP are mostly a holdover from PHP 4.  In PHP 5, references are not needed in most cases where you would be tempted to use them.

The PHP manual on [Returning References](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) says (emphasis is theirs):

> Do ***not*** use return-by-reference to increase performance. The engine will automatically optimize this on its own. Only return references when you have a valid technical reason to do so.

If you do need to clone an array reference, then you can copy it by value this way:

```
$row = unserialize(serialize($row));
```

Comment: Ok, so this is vaguely frightening because what you seem to be suggesting is that, owing to some performance considerations, the actual behaviour of the code becomes unpredictable.  At no point does my code use references in returning the content to $row and yet it is quite obvious that a reference is what results.  I can also add (I did not want earlier - thought my OP was stupid enough) that the results from this function varied, depending on where it was called from.  Optmization may well account for that.

Comment: Bill, I just followed your link to Schlüter.  This is a very interesting article.  Strangely, though, if you follow his logic to the end, then I should still get the result I want.  When I do my 2nd fetch, which will refill the memory area that is now shared with $rows[0], it follows that PHP should perform a copy-on-write.  It does not.  So perhaps it's a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet that `$res->fetch()` is returning a [reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.phpt) for some reason...  Try doing this to break the reference:

```
while ($row= $res->fetch()) {
    echo $row['ccorID'] . "\r\n";
    $rows[]= $row;
    echo $rows[0]['ccorID'] . "\r\n";
    unset($row);
}
```

(Noticed the added `unset` at the end)...

Comment: Appreciate the idea.  Tried it.  No difference.

Answer (score 0):

i would try array_merge(), but its not clear what the intention of this function is, quick fix just add an indexer because what you are doing is just copying the reference and on every row you just update where the reference is pointing to